# Get specific Keyword on strings

Tags: .net, regex

i'm not a regex expert but i know how to make simple regex. But when it comes to this type, how do you search for a specific text like "SU","RU","IN". Here's a sample data:

The string is like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What part of matching text like SU, RU, IN are you finding it difficult?

Comment: Please add more details. The example text as text, not as image. Where is your problem? What do you want to match (What should be your result) and what is your expression actually matching?

Comment: Its difficult because of its format, the image above is exactly the structure of the string that im working on. The problem is, i wanted to get the specific word "IN".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match exactly the word "IN" and not "INPUT" then you have to use word boundaries.

```
\bIN\b
```

The word boundary `\b` matches the change from a word character (All letters, digits and the underscore) to a non word character (All other characters).

If you have a list of those words you can put them in a list (already combined with the word boundaries)

```
\b(IN|SU|RU)\b
```

This would match either "IN" or "SU" or "RU"

If this answer didn't solved your problem, then please add more details to your question.

**Because of the request in the comment:**

of course its possible to get more details from the row. To answer this I am making some assumptions about your data (because there is only a picture)

1. I assume you are reading this row by row
2. The row looks something like "test -----      -------- IN 0/0"
3. The "test" is directly at the beginning of the row

You can then get the "test" with using `RegexOptions.Multiline` (this is needed to make the `^` match the start of the row)

```
^(\w+).*?\b(IN|SU|RU)\b
```

The first word is in capturing group 1 and the keyword is in group 2.

Comment: Thanks! that solves my problem. One other thing, how do i know which identifier was found?

Comment: Because of the brackets the found string is stored in the capturing group 1. in c# you get it, if `m` is of type `Matcher` something like this `m.group(1)`

Comment: Is it also possible to get the "Job Name" e.g. test

Comment: @ivatanako I updated my answer. In general its not good to expand the questions in the comments (for later readers difficult to follow), please, the next time think a bit more about your question and what you want to achieve.